# Keep WPF Calendar open after date selection from DatePicker

Tags: wpf, datepicker, calendar, popup

I'm attempting to customise the WPF DatePicker and it's calendar popup component to keep the popup open after the user has selected a date. This is due to the extension to the style I have made that allows the user to select a time.
The calendar should only be closed once the user has clicked a 'finished' button in the style.

I've made multiple attempts at doing this, each with varying degrees of success but I have to admit, a fully working solution has eluded me.

Example solution using an override on IsDropDownOpen;

```
IsDropDownOpenProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomDatePicker), new 
FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
OnIsDropDownOpenChanged, OnCoerceIsDropDownOpen));

private static object OnCoerceIsDropDownOpen(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var instance = d as CustomDatePicker;
        if (instance != null)
        {
            if (instance.CalendarPopup.IsOpen == false)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var coalesed = (bool) baseValue;

            if (coalesed == false)
            {
                return instance.PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection;
            }
        }

        return baseValue;
    }
```

'PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection' is a dependency property I have created so that this behaviour is customizable.

Is an example of the popup staying open and closing when the user clicks 'done' however the popup will no longer reopen after interacting with the datepicker button.

Am I missing something obvious with this approach / is there a working solution?

EDIT:

ROOT CONTROL

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Threading;

using Calendar = System.Windows.Controls.Calendar;

namespace CommonControls.Calendar
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = NavigationPreviousButtonPartName, Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = NavigationNextButtonPartName, Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = NavigationTodayButtonPartName, Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = NavigationDoneButtonPartName, Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = DatePickerButtonPartName, Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = DatePickerTextBoxPartName, Type = typeof(DatePickerTextBox))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = CalendarPopupPartName, Type = typeof(Popup))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = DatePickerDisplayTextBoxPartName, Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
    public class ExtendedDatePicker : DatePicker
    {
        public const string DatePickerDisplayTextBoxPartName = "PART_DisplayDateTextBox";
        public const string DatePickerButtonPartName = "PART_Button";
        public const string DatePickerTextBoxPartName = "PART_TextBox";
        public const string CalendarPopupPartName = "PART_Popup";
        public const string NavigationPreviousButtonPartName = "PART_NavPreviousButton";
        public const string NavigationNextButtonPartName = "PART_NavNextButton";
        public const string NavigationTodayButtonPartName = "PART_TodayButton";
        public const string NavigationDoneButtonPartName = "PART_DoneButton";

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BlackoutDatesInPastProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BlackoutDatesInPast", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(true, BlackoutDatesInPastPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ThrowExceptionOnBlackoutDateSelectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ThrowExceptionOnBlackoutDateSelection", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DatePickerButtonTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DatePickerButtonTemplate", typeof(ControlTemplate), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CustomDateFormatProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CustomDateFormat", typeof(string), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata("d", CustomDateFormatPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseCustomDateFormatProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UseCustomDateFormat", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(false, UseCustomDateFormatPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowTodayButtonProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ShowTodayButton", typeof(bool), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(false, ShowTodayButtonPropertyChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DaysToJumpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DaysToJump", typeof(int), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(1));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MonthsToJumpProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MonthsToJump", typeof(int), typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(1));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty PopupStaysOpenAfterSelectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection", typeof(bool),
                typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        protected DatePickerTextBox DatePickerTextBox;

        protected Calendar InternalCalendar;

        protected Popup CalendarPopup;

        protected bool PendingClose = false;

        private Button _navigationPreviousButton;

        private Button _navigationNextButton;

        private Button _navigationTodayButton;

        private Button _navigationDoneButton;

        private Button _datePickerButton;

        private TextBlock _displayDateTextBlock;

        static ExtendedDatePicker()
        {
            IsDropDownOpenProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, ExtendedOnIsDropDownOpenChanged, OnCoerceIsDropDownOpen));
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDatePicker), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDatePicker)));
        }

        private static object OnCoerceIsDropDownOpen(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
        {
            var instance = d as ExtendedDatePicker;
            if (!instance.IsEnabled)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!instance.PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection)
            {
                return basevalue;
            }

            if (instance.PendingClose)
            {
                instance.PendingClose = false;
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        /**
         * OLD
        private static object OnCoerceIsDropDownOpen(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
        {
            var instance = d as ExtendedDatePicker;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                if (instance.IsDropDownOpen == false)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                var coalesed = (bool) baseValue;

                if (coalesed == false)
                {
                    return instance.PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection;
                }
            }

            return baseValue;
        }
    */

        private static void ExtendedOnIsDropDownOpenChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var instance = (ExtendedDatePicker) d;
            instance.CoerceValue(IsDropDownOpenProperty);
        }

        public bool BlackoutDatesInPast
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(BlackoutDatesInPastProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BlackoutDatesInPastProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool ThrowExceptionOnBlackoutDateSelection
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ThrowExceptionOnBlackoutDateSelectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ThrowExceptionOnBlackoutDateSelectionProperty, value); }
        }

        public ControlTemplate DatePickerButtonTemplate
        {
            get { return (ControlTemplate)GetValue(DatePickerButtonTemplateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DatePickerButtonTemplateProperty, value); }
        }

        public string CustomDateFormat
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(CustomDateFormatProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CustomDateFormatProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool UseCustomDateFormat
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(UseCustomDateFormatProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UseCustomDateFormatProperty, value); }
        }

        public bool PopupStaysOpenAfterSelection
        {
            get { return (bool) GetValue(PopupStaysOpenAfterSelectionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PopupStaysOpenAfterSelectionProperty, value);}
        }

        public bool ShowTodayButton
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowTodayButtonProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ShowTodayButtonProperty, value); }
        }

        public int DaysToJump
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(DaysToJumpProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DaysToJumpProperty, value); }
        }

        public int MonthsToJump
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MonthsToJumpProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MonthsToJumpProperty, value); }
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            _datePickerButton = GetTemplateChild(DatePickerButtonPartName) as Button;
            _datePickerButton.CreateBinding(TemplateProperty, this, nameof(DatePickerButtonTemplate));

            DatePickerTextBox = GetTemplateChild(DatePickerTextBoxPartName) as DatePickerTextBox;
            _displayDateTextBlock = GetTemplateChild(DatePickerDisplayTextBoxPartName) as TextBlock;
            CalendarPopup = GetTemplateChild(CalendarPopupPartName) as Popup;

            InternalCalendar = CalendarPopup.Child as Calendar;
            InternalCalendar.ApplyTemplate();

            CalendarPopup.Loaded += CalendarPopup_Loaded;

            _navigationPreviousButton = GetTemplateChild(NavigationPreviousButtonPartName) as Button;
            _navigationNextButton = GetTemplateChild(NavigationNextButtonPartName) as Button;

            _navigationTodayButton = InternalCalendar.Template.FindName(NavigationTodayButtonPartName, InternalCalendar) as Button;
            _navigationDoneButton = InternalCalendar.Template.FindName(NavigationDoneButtonPartName, InternalCalendar) as Button;

            if (_navigationTodayButton != null)
            {
                _navigationTodayButton.Click += TodayButton_Click;
            }

            if (_navigationPreviousButton != null)
            {
                _navigationPreviousButton.Click += NavPreviousButton_Click;
            }

            if (_navigationNextButton != null)
            {
                _navigationNextButton.Click += NavNextButton_Click;
            }

            if (_navigationDoneButton != null)
            {
                _navigationDoneButton.Click += NavDoneButton_Click;
            }

            RefreshBlackOutDates();
            RefreshDisplayDate();
            RefreshTextControlsVisibility();
            RefreshTodayButtonVisibility();
        }

        private void CalendarPopup_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSelectedDateChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSelectedDateChanged(e);

            RefreshDisplayDate();
        }

        private static void BlackoutDatesInPastPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = (ExtendedDatePicker)d;
            source.RefreshBlackOutDates();
        }

        private static void CustomDateFormatPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = (ExtendedDatePicker)d;
            source.RefreshDisplayDate();
        }

        private static void UseCustomDateFormatPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = (ExtendedDatePicker)d;
            source.RefreshTextControlsVisibility();
            source.RefreshDisplayDate();
        }

        private static void ShowTodayButtonPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = (ExtendedDatePicker)d;
            source.RefreshTodayButtonVisibility();
        }

        private void RefreshTextControlsVisibility()
        {
            if (DatePickerTextBox != null
                && _displayDateTextBlock != null)
            {
                DatePickerTextBox.Visibility = UseCustomDateFormat ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                _displayDateTextBlock.Visibility = !UseCustomDateFormat ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }

        private void RefreshTodayButtonVisibility()
        {
            if (_navigationTodayButton != null)
            {
                _navigationTodayButton.Visibility = ShowTodayButton ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }

        private void RefreshDisplayDate()
        {
            if (_displayDateTextBlock != null)
            {
                if (UseCustomDateFormat
                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CustomDateFormat))
                {
                    if (SelectedDate.HasValue)
                    {
                        var d = SelectedDate.Value;

                        _displayDateTextBlock.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, d.ToString(CustomDateFormat));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _displayDateTextBlock.Text = "Select a date";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void RefreshBlackOutDates()
        {
            if (BlackoutDatesInPast)
            {
                BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
            }
        }

        private void GoToToday()
        {
            var newDate = DateTime.Today;
            GoToDate(newDate);
        }

        private void GoToNextDate()
        {
            var selectedDate = SelectedDate;
            if (selectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                var newDate = selectedDate.Value;

                if (DaysToJump > 0)
                {
                    newDate = newDate.AddDays(DaysToJump);
                }

                if (MonthsToJump > 0)
                {
                    newDate = newDate.AddMonths(MonthsToJump);
                }

                GoToDate(newDate);
            }
        }

        private void GoToPreviousDate()
        {
            var selectedDate = SelectedDate;
            if (selectedDate.HasValue)
            {
                var newDate = selectedDate.Value;
                if (DaysToJump > 0)
                {
                    newDate = newDate.AddDays(DaysToJump * -1);
                }

                if (MonthsToJump > 0)
                {
                    newDate = newDate.AddMonths(MonthsToJump * -1);
                }

                GoToDate(newDate);
            }
        }

        private void GoToDate(DateTime date)
        {
            if (!BlackoutDates.Contains(date))
            {
                SelectedDate = date;
            }
        }

        private void NavNextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoToNextDate();
        }

        private void NavPreviousButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoToPreviousDate();
        }

        private void TodayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            GoToToday();
        }

        private void NavDoneButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsDropDownOpen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

WITH TIME

```
public class CustomDatePickerWithTime : ExtendedDatePicker
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty MinuteIntervalProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "MinuteInterval", typeof(int), typeof(ExtendedDatePickerWithTime), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(30));

        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey AvailableTimesPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
            "AvailableTimes", typeof(List<TimeSpan>), typeof(ExtendedDatePickerWithTime),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AvailableTimesProperty = AvailableTimesPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "SelectedTime", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(ExtendedDatePickerWithTime), new PropertyMetadata(default(TimeSpan), OnSelectedTimePropertyChanged));

        static ExtendedDatePickerWithTime()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDatePickerWithTime),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ExtendedDatePickerWithTime)));
        }

        public int MinuteInterval
        {
            get { return (int) GetValue(MinuteIntervalProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MinuteIntervalProperty, value);}
        }

        public List<TimeSpan> AvailableTimes
        {
            get { return (List<TimeSpan>) GetValue(AvailableTimesProperty); }
            protected set { SetValue(AvailableTimesPropertyKey, value);}
        }

        public TimeSpan SelectedTime
        {
            get { return (TimeSpan) GetValue(SelectedTimeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedTimeProperty, value);}
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            CheckIntervalConstraintsAndConstruct();
            OverrideTextBoxEntryStyle();
        }

        private void OverrideTextBoxEntryStyle()
        {
        }

        private static void OnSelectedTimePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var instance = (ExtendedDatePickerWithTime) d;

            instance.SelectedDate = instance.SelectedDate?.Date.Add(instance.SelectedTime) ?? DateTime.Today.Add(instance.SelectedTime);
        }

        private void CheckIntervalConstraintsAndConstruct()
        {
            if (60 % MinuteInterval != 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(MinuteInterval), @"The supplied interval in minutes must be divisible by 60");
            }

            var times = new List<TimeSpan>();

            var starting = DateTime.Today;
            var ending = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

            for (var ts = starting; ts <= ending.AddMinutes(MinuteInterval *-1); ts = ts.AddMinutes(MinuteInterval))
            {
                times.Add(ts.TimeOfDay);
            }

            AvailableTimes = times;
        }
    }
```

XAML: (length exceeds allowed body)

https://pastebin.com/W9KrtM8E

Comment: you haven't posted the related code to the problem.

Comment: The code I've provided is an attempted solution, that presents the specified bug. The problem is more of 'is it possible out of the box', I've merely extended the DatePicker control here;

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DatePicker.cs,c20427230c18ba13

Comment: Looking to necro this post.

Comment: Full control now added